# Problem setting up a copy of my site

Tags: magento-1.7, installation

I wanted to make a copy of my site on my local server in order to use it as a development site. I made a backup of the database and restored it in the server, then I changed the values of web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to point to my local server (http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/mySite/). I copied the whole directory into my server, then I proceeded to manually delete the content of sessions and cache and also I ran the re-indexing script. After that I changed the values of /app/etc/local.xml to point to my database. That's all the process, right? Well, nothing happened, I can't see my store. I got this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 73: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: reference line 72 and customer_logged_out  in /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php on line 28352

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/chromo...', 28352, Array)
#1 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(28352): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'chromo', 'default', '1')
#3 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(28255): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(28154): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(28132): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(13760): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(11176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(11119): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /var/www/chromo/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(13872): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(18234): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(17768): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/chromo/includes/src/__default.php(20368): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/chromo/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/chromo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

But I do have access to my backend. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the layout update xml for you homepage is not well formatted.
Go to the backend to CMS->Pages edit the homepage (the one with identifier `home`) and take a looks at the field `Layout XML updates`. Try to make the xml in there valid.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked the Layout XML Updates but I couldn't find anything that seemed wrong to me. Here's what I got:
<reference name="head">
  <block type="core/text" name="chromo_style">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link href="/skin/frontend/chromo/default/css/chromo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="chromo_style">]]></text></action>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text" name="chromo_js">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="/skin/frontend/chromo/default/js/chromo_js.js"></script>]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>

Comment: @Sebastian. I looked closely at the error message and just realized I was wrong. It looks like the error is in one of the layout xml files of your theme. Look in the layout files for the text `customer_logged_out` and see which one of the layout files that contains it is not valid.

Comment: I checked those files, to be honest I don't know what am I looking for, everything looks normal to me. But I'm wondering, if the same files are working on my live server, why not here? I made an exact copy and just changed but I told you in the description, nothing else.

Comment: My installation was originally on the root folder, the copy it's gonna be under /var/www/mySite, who should I point the intallation to /var/www/mySite?